# Regular expressions on Scala - Searching from the beginning of String

Tags: java, scala

Currently, when I search for "th" it matches with "the" "these" and "other"...I don't want "other" because it is not at the beginning of the word.

I'm trying to use regular expressions on Scala and I am running into some problems.  I am having trouble implementing "\A" which matches at the beginning of a string.

I'm working on an autocomplete tool with the code seen below and currently I'm using contains...however it matches on any part of the word.  What's the best way for it to only match from the start of the word using \A?

```
val newList = ArrayBuffer[String]()
val pattern = new Regex (\\A searchText)

def searchList (searchText:String):Unit = {
    println("Search has been called")
    println(searchText)
    for(s <- words){
        println("for test")
        if(s contains(searchText)){
            println("if test")
            newList += s
             println(newList.mkString("\n"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex. You don't even use `pattern` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startsWith` instead of `contains`, to search from the beginning of the string.